# SugarCRM Scheduler Not Calling runProcessManager Module

Tags: cron, scheduler, sugarcrm

I'm running Sugar Pro, version 5.5.4, on Ubuntu 9.10, Apache 2.2, MySQL 5.1.28, and PHP 5.2.10.

I have a module called Process Manager setup and running. I can manually make this go, to send email when new leads are created, and even use filters. So the functionality works.

But as soon as I create a Scheduler to make this go, I run into problems. My "user" crontab is:

`* * * * * cd /var/www/sugarcrm; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

And the Scheduler is set to run every minute of every day. But when I create a new lead with the filter field correct, there is no email after several minutes of waiting.

After 5 minutes or so, I can go to the Process Manager module, click on "Run Process Manager" and the email appears seconds later.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as mentioned here:
"Now the Scheduler talks to the Process Manager but the process stalls as a job. The Job Log shows "In Progress" for this job/process, and fails after an hour (assuming due to a timeout). I am looking for A) a solution (because someone has seen this before, etc) or B) a method to better track why and where it's stalling." Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set permissions to 777 for the entire directory.  Now this works, but the jobs stall when I create an item that requires the Scheduler to call the Process Manager.  I will create another question for this new issue.